# How fill up the datepicker form with string date?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

From database I get data in format like (let's suppose it's a string)

> 1974-07-05

How I need to pass the date in form with datepicker and make the date active there, so how can I do it?

```
<td>
   <script src="javascript/datepicker.js"></script>
   <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob" value="${person.bdate}">
</td>
```

and ${person.bdate} is a string date

Comment: Format your date into `mm/dd/yyyy`, then set it into the `value`. Or change your datepickers format into `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: so all I need to do is to pass the date into `value` with the `mm/dd/yyyy` format? actualy the datepicker format is `dd-mm-yy`

Comment: By default the datepickers format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. So when you initialize your datepicker set `dateFormat` to `yy-mm-dd`. Or you can change your format to match the default.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Please add your solution as a formal answer so it can be upvoted and (hopefully) selected as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just an observation.

You have requested a pure javascript solution, but you are using a plugin. Why not use jQuery and jQueryUI's datepicker plugin. Look how easy the code would be:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5b2cncms/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob" value="">
```

**jQuery:**

```
var dd = '1974-07-05';
$('#datepicker').val(dd);

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Sources:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: good solution, but I just initialized the datepicker with yy-mm-dd and it works

Comment: Good to hear! Keep on going, and good luck with your project.